# Post multiple clicks in a table to different consecutive input text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick

I have the following partially completed code example that clicking on any table cell populates the first`input` text box. I'd like 2nd and 3rd clicks in the table to populate the 2nd and 3rd input fields. And if a fourth text cell is clicked, it starts the count over by populating from the first field, etc.

There's also a small bug in the function that when the page first loads, it doesn't recognize the first mouse click. It takes a 2nd click to populate the first field.

Thank you in advance for helping me solve this and learn from it. :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td:hover { cursor: hand; color: blue; font-weight: bold; background: #FFDE00; }
    </style>
</head>

<body >

    <p>Click on a cell to have it populate the text fields below<p>

    <table border="1" onclick="populateFields()" style=font-size:11; cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tr><td>apple</td><td>orange</td><td>banana</td><td>peach</td></tr>
        <tr><td>tomato</td><td>potato</td><td>onion</td><td>garlic</td></tr>
        <tr><td>chicken</td><td>fish</td><td>beef</td><td>pork</td></tr>
    </table>

    <form>
        <p>The cells you clicked on contain this data:</p>
        <input type="text" name="item1" id="txtCellData"></input>
        <input type="text" name="item2" id="textCellData2"></input>
        <input type="text" name="item3" id="textCellData3"></input>
    </form>

    <script> 
        function populateFields(){
            //put all tds in an array
            var alltds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

            //go through each item in the array
            for (var i in alltds) {
              alltds[i].onclick = function (){
                txtCellData.value = this.innerHTML;
              }
            }
        }

        function setThis(value) {
            document.getElementById("txtCellData").value = value;
        }
    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fiddle for you . Look at this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/b3GuX/6/)

```
<body onload=populateFields() >

<p>Click on a cell to have it populate the text fields below<p>

<table border="1" onclick="populateFields()" style=font-size:11; cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr><td>apple</td><td>orange</td><td>banana</td><td>peach</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tomato</td><td>potato</td><td>onion</td><td>garlic</td></tr>
    <tr><td>chicken</td><td>fish</td><td>beef</td><td>pork</td></tr>
</table>

<form>
    <p>The cells you clicked on contain this data:</p>
    <input type="text" name="item1" id="txtCellData"></input>
    <input type="text" name="item2" id="textCellData2"></input>
    <input type="text" name="item3" id="textCellData3"></input>
    </form></body>
<script>
var index=0;
function populateFields(){
        //put all tds in an array
        var alltds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

        //go through each item in the array
        for (var i in alltds) {
          alltds[i].onclick = function (){


             if(index==1){txtCellData.value = this.innerHTML;}
                else{
                    setThis(this.innerHTML);
                    }
          }
        }

        if(index<3){
             index++;
            }else{
                   index = 1;
                  }
            alert(index);

}

    function setThis(value) {
        document.getElementById("textCellData"+index).value = value;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Awesome, solution. Thank you for your time and consideration--AND for creating the fiddle. I see how this works now with both functions "sharing" the scope of 'index' and concatenating that to textCellData. Good lesson for me. Thanks, again. :)